# I found code that I would like to use in my Dev Org, but I don't know how to. Can anyone offer guidance on implementing this code?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

[Here's a link](http://lexnetsvn.repositoryhosting.com/svn_public/lexnetsvn_personaccountsaddon/Lexnet%20-%20Person%20Accounts/src/classes/) to the code that I would like to implement in my Developer Edition org. The code is used to offer a combination of B2B and B2C in the same org *without* using person accounts.

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: To clarify, I've so far just copied and pasted the code into the proper place (class, trigger, page, etc.) and created the fields manually, but I feel like I'm missing a better way to be doing this.

UPDATE: Copying and pasting each code item in seems to have worked, in addition to a few manual changes indicated in the readme, however, it still refers to 'Downloading the Code', which makes me feel like there is a better way to do this than just copying and pasting all of the code over. Any idea what this is referring to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by DavinC, the [Force.com IDE](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) is the most common way of handling code deployments, although there is also a [command line tool called ant](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Migration_Tool_Guide) that salesforce provides a toolkit for using in deployments.

The IDE however is far friendlier to non-developers, although it's still a rather large and complex peice of software.

If I wanted to deploy that source to my org I'd download the whole thing, from the [root level](http://lexnetsvn.repositoryhosting.com/svn_public/lexnetsvn_personaccountsaddon/Lexnet%20-%20Person%20Accounts/) and then load the project into the IDE. From there the IDE has a deploy menu that can be used to push all of the data at once to your org.

For small projects it can be faster to copy/paste as you've done but once you start working with large projects that include dozens of classes or workflows it quickly becomes more efficient to invest in learning the IDE.

Comment: Thanks, this might be a stupid question, but from the link you provided to 'root level', how do you actually download the project?

Comment: That's a whole other can of worms. It's actually hosted using a tool called subversion (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion), which you can think of a fancy folder except that it keeps track of who made changes, when, and why.

The best windows tool for working with subversion (aka svn for short) repositories is probably tortiseSVN (http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Force.com IDE to manage this code.

[Force.com IDE](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE)